# how to put an image into UIImagePickerController on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My aim is for the user to capture a screen shot from a `UIwebView` and then load the image into a `UIPopoverController`. From the `UIPopoverController` the user can then crop and save the image.

So far I can capture the screen shot a save as a `UIImage`. Then, my `UIPopoverController` pops up but without the saved image. This is because my `imagePicker sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;` What would I replace this with???

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageView.image = viewImage;

    [imageView setHidden:NO];

    // this removes current view ie photoLibary
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    // this checks that a popover is not already in view
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) 
   {
        // if yes - remove
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

   } 
   else 
   {     
        // create an imagePicker

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;


        // create an PopoverController
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                             initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];



        popoverController.delegate = self;


        UIView *popView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
        [self.view addSubview:popView];

        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,200, 565, 545)
                                           inView:self.view
                         permittedArrowDirections:0
                                         animated:YES];
    }

    return viewImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

like this

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
        [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        imageView.image = viewImage;


            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self performSelector:@selector(call) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];

        }

-(void)call
{
 if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {

    // if yes - remove
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

} else {

    // create an imagePicker

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;


    // create an PopoverController
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                         initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];



    popoverController.delegate = self;


    UIView *popView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
    [self.view addSubview:popView];




    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,200, 565, 545)
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:0
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it help You

Comment: wow !! thats excellent. I couldn't get the PopoverController to load at the same time as saving the image but the call method and delay works really great. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the following code to save the image into the photo album.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToBeSaved, nil, nil, nil);
```

you can refer the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) to know more about that function.